# How to know if the lightbox2 has been loaded or closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox2

I'm using this library:

https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#help

I need to know when the image is loaded or when it is closed, as an 'onload' or 'onhide' element.
I need to call a function when the image is loaded.

Comment: Doesn't look like Lightbox2 has any hooks or events to attach to so you won't be able to do that.

Comment: is there any way to access the library's internal property and add an event?